# Can not start up, show following error?

Tags: 20.04, startup

This is the error, doesn't start up ubuntu, I have tried to purge Nvidia but it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could boot from a recovery disk or usb system and check the log messages in /var/log to see what blocks your boot process, perhaps some filesystem issue.